# aDecoder crash when try to fetch nil value also encoding decoding enum values not working

Tags: swift, enums, swift4, decode, encode

I have a class with some properties, and I am using encode while saving and decoder while fetching, but some of the data are not optional, but at the first time when I am fetching it's null so when the decoder is calling and it found nill value it crashes the app.

So what I want is when I fetch the data and if no data found I can set some default value instead of crashing I can solve this by making those properties optional but I don't want that. and also not able to add try catch to make sure it doesn't crash

Please tell what changes should I make to this class and also share some example or links or tutorial that explains everything about encoder and decoder in depth (not some medium article with just overview)

I am new to swift so if you find anything wrong with this class do tell in comments and best ways to do with latest swift

```
import Foundation

enum AcModeType {
    case acModeCool
    case acModeDry
    case acModeHeat
    case acModeFan
    case acModeTimer
}

enum FanModeType {
    case fanModeLow
    case fanModeMid
    case fanModeHigh
    case FanModeAuto
}

class AcDevice: Device {
    var brandId: String?
    var variant: String?
    var brandName: String?
    var acTemperature: Int = 16
    var acMinTemperature: Int = 16
    var acMaxTemperature: Int = 32
    var weatherTemperature: Int = 0
    var roomTemperature: Int = 0
    var timeTable = [TimeTable]()
    var currentAcMode: AcModeType = .acModeCool
    var currentFanMode: FanModeType = .fanModeLow
    var lastPowerOnTime: Double = 0.0
    var isPowerOn = false
    var isSleepOn = false
    var isTimeTableOn = false
    var hasScreen = false

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init();
        brandId             =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "brandId") as! String?)
        variant             =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "variant") as! String?)
        brandName           =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "brandName") as! String?)
        acTemperature       =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "temperature") as! Int)
        acMinTemperature    =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "acMinTemperature") as! Int )
        acMaxTemperature    =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "acMaxTemperature") as! Int )
        weatherTemperature  =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "weatherTemperature") as! Int)
        roomTemperature     =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "roomTemperature") as! Int )
        currentAcMode       =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "currentAcMode") as! AcModeType)
        currentFanMode      =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "currentFanMode") as! FanModeType)
        lastPowerOnTime     =   (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "lastPowerOnTime") as! Double)
        if let timeTable    =   aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "timeTable") as! [TimeTable]? {self.timeTable=timeTable}
    }

    public override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.brandId, forKey: "brandId")
        aCoder.encode(self.variant, forKey: "variant")
        aCoder.encode(self.brandName, forKey: "brandName")
        aCoder.encode(self.acTemperature, forKey: "temperature")
        aCoder.encode(self.timeTable, forKey: "timeTable")
        aCoder.encode(self.acMinTemperature, forKey: "acMinTemperature")
        aCoder.encode(self.acMaxTemperature, forKey: "acMaxTemperature")
        aCoder.encode(self.weatherTemperature, forKey: "weatherTemperature")
        aCoder.encode(self.roomTemperature, forKey: "roomTemperature")
        aCoder.encode(self.currentAcMode, forKey: "currentAcMode")
        aCoder.encode(self.currentFanMode, forKey: "currentFanMode")
        aCoder.encode(self.lastPowerOnTime, forKey: "lastPowerOnTime")
    }

    required public init() {
        super.init();
        brandId = ""
        variant = ""
        brandName = ""

        isPowerOn = false;
        isSleepOn = false;
        isTimeTableOn = false;
        hasScreen = false;
        currentAcMode = .acModeCool
        acMinTemperature = 16;
        acMaxTemperature = 32;
        currentFanMode = .fanModeLow
        lastPowerOnTime = -1;
        timeTable = [TimeTable]()
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh god, so many `as!`. No wonder it crashes. You should really tone down force casting (and unwrapping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` you're using `as!` to force cast the results of `decodeObject`, so this will crash your app if it fails. Instead you could use `as?` in combination with a default value to unwrap your optionals.

For example:

```
brandId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "brandId") as? String ?? "your default string"
```

This uses `??` which is the nil coalescing operator to provide a default value when the left hand side is nil.

Comment: Or, better, instead of post-parsing casting, use methods like [`decodeObject(of:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoder/2292924-decodeobject).

Comment: Can I decode enum also? while encoding enum value it crashes

Comment: You could add a raw value to you enums like `enum AcModeType: Int` then encode/decode using the raw values `yourEnum.rawValue` and `let value = AcModeType(rawValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `Codable` protocols in swift. Just have a look at the below link.

https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999

and,

**Apple documentation for this:**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: Can you add some essential quotes from the links you've provided? Because, as you know, links can become invalid in future.